# PySpark is not starting from Windows Command Prompt

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to start pyspark from windows cmd. But so far no luck. I am getting an error msg as shown  below. 
[image]

I have gone through almost every corner of stackoverflow and net search but could not able to fix this.

So far I have followed the steps as mentioned below:

1. set JAVA_HOME, SPARK_HOME and HADOOP_HOME in the System Variables.

[image]

2. Update the PATH variables as shown below.

[image]

I have managed all the 'space' related issues. Despite all these, I am still not able to start the spark-shell or pyspark from command prompt.

I am using Windows 10 Home edition.

Am I missing out something?

Note: I have installed Java, Scala and Python and from command prompt they are running fine.

Comment: Please do not use pictures in your question. A hint to your problem is here `The system cannot find the path specified`. `pyspark` is a script. While executing this script the script is trying to execute a program. This line to execute has an error. The hint on this error is `\Microsoft was unexpected at this time.`. Debug the script `pyspark`. You will find a line with Microsoft in it, This line has an error that you must correct. Often the solution is to put quotes around the path as Windows paths often have spaces in them.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable access to the default scratch directory for Hive. Make sure the directory C:\tmp\hive exists; if it doesn’t exist, create it.
Next, you need to give to it a permission to access winutils.exe. Navigate back to where you put this .exe file then run the permission command

```
cd c:\hadoop\bin
winutils.exe chmod -R 777 C:\tmp\hive
```

Once you have completed this try again to launch PySpark!

Comment: I have tried this option after your post. Again I am getting the same issue.

Comment: Other things to lookout for: space and paranthese in env variable value like the following ->  C:\Program Files (x86)\...try to double quote those strings!